# Nested views without nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Following this tutorial: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views, i'm able to create an application with multiple views defined in a root template. I need to modify that scheme a bit by putting `tabledata` and `graph` to a child view called `content`. I want my views to look like that:

#### index.html

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

#### content.html

```
<div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
<div ui-view="graph"></div>
```

And my routes looks like that:

```
# ...

.state('videos',
  url:         '/videos'
  templateUrl: 'content.html'
  views:
    'tabledata':
      templateUrl: 'tabledata.html'
      controller:  '...'

    'sidebar':
      templateUrl: 'graph.html'
      controller:  '...'
)
```

However, when pointing my browser to `/videos`, `tabledata.html` and `graph.html` templates are not loaded to corresponding views. Everything works great though, if i'll put `tabledata` and `graph` views to **index.html**

I'm sure there is something really wrong with my code but i'm not able to figure out what exactly nor google anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can only have multiple `ui-view`'s in multiple named views, i.e.when you explicitly declare a `views` property on your state definition. I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but if you would like to have control over where hese ui-views load their states then you can use an abstract state, from the link you provided:

> **Views override state's template properties**
>
> If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and
>   templateProvider will be ignored. So in the case that you need a
>   parent layout of these views, you can define an abstract state that
>   contains a template, and a child state under the layout state that
>   contains the 'views' object.

This is what I suggest:

```
.state('videos',{
  url:         '/videos',
  templateUrl: 'content.html',
  abstract: true})
.state('videos.xyz',{
  url: '/xyz',//you can leave this empty if you like
  {
    views:{
    'tabledata':{
      templateUrl: 'tabledata.html'
      controller:  '...'
      },

    'sidebar':{
      templateUrl: 'graph.html'
      controller:  '...'
     }
  }
 })
```

If you don't want that xyz appended to your url's, just pass in an empty string for the url property of the state `videos.xyz`. I use this approach all the time, let me know if it's what you're after.